# Doing a project for college for a manned drone theortically only

Tags: quadcopter, dynamics, brushless-motor

Weight of the Drone in total will be 240 Kg.

It Will be a quad copter drone setup but with 8 rotors(two on each corner) for redundancy purpose.
Aim is achieve Thrust/weight ratio of 2.
So need total needed thrust will be 500 KG.
Considering 500 kg thrust by 4 rotors only(because the 2nd rotor on each corner if fails the 1st motor should be able to compensate thrust) , each should be able to produce 125 kg thrust.
The propeller Diameter will be 1.2 m  ( Total 8 propeller)
Now coming to the question:
What should be the power rating of the motor if i want 125 kg thrust from each Propeller (When running at 85%-95% of the max RPM.)

If you have any Doubts or any details please ask ,will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: If you want people to help you, could you invest some seconds to fix your text (or at least the typos?)

Comment: Yes sure. Please tell.

Comment: What should I tell you?

Comment: For safety you better have all motors running at all times, otherwise failure detection + engagement time delay may result in uncontrollable flight. This means you have to optimize for 500kg thrust with 8 motors. Also, the thrust to weight of 2 is more than necessary for an emergency landing, but I’ll live with that as this is a theoretical study.

Comment: Hi Cetin, All the motors will be running all the time. When all are running each motor thrust is only 125/2=62.5Kg. But if one motor on one corner fails the other one should be able to produce 125kg thrust(compensation), so il be taking motor which is capable to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thrust vs. power is not constant -- it depends strongly on prop diameter (bigger diameter = more thrust/watt).  It depends less strongly on a bunch of other factors that I would know in detail if I were an aerodynamics expert, which I'm not.

Getting that part right would be a huge part of a real design.  I suggest, since this is a theoretical preliminary study, that you find some books on propeller design, and some on helicopter rotor design, and make a stab at estimating the prop size and motor power, with enough material for a section on the relevant trade-offs so that your instructors know you paid attention to it, and so that any follow-on researchers know where to look for more information.

Comment: I'm in contact with Propeller manufacturer and Motor manufacturer will be exchanging details with them and will be coming to a conclusion as to which will be the right propeller for motor. Will update the question once i get them. Propeller dia of 1.25 meter is restriction because of size constraints. The bigger the propeller the better because the DISK LOADING (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_loading) will be less , hence efficiency of the blade increases and less power is consumed .

Comment: As per my calculation, the motor power will be approx to 13-15 Kw each.